# Simple epsilon proof help

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The question I am trying to answer is
"Prove that for all $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$, if $|x − 2| < \frac{\varepsilon}{7}$ then $|x^2 − 4| < \varepsilon$."

My attempt is the following:

Suppose that  $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$. Let $|x-2|< \frac{\varepsilon}{7}$. Now consider
\begin{align*}
|x^2 - 4|&=|x-2||x+2|\\
         &=|x-2||x-2+4|\\
         &< \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{7}  + 4\right) \\
         &<7 \frac{\varepsilon}{7} \\
         &= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
QED

However I'm not too sure whether the last two lines are correct. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you sure???

Comment: Just haven't done these types of proofs in a while, so was a bit rusty

Comment: I meant: which point *precisely* is not obvious to you?

Comment: It was going from the third step to the fourth step. I wasn't too sure if I could say that 4+epsilon/7 is less than 7 for some reason.

Comment: 4+epsilon/7<4+1/7<5<7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are valid. You just used the triangular inequality as
$$|x+2|=|x-2+4|\leq |x-2|+4<\frac{\varepsilon}{7}+4<\frac{1}{7}+4<7$$
so, indeed, $|x^2-4|=|x-2|\cdot|x+2|<\frac{\varepsilon}{7}\cdot7=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Really appreciate it thanks!